# How to write storybook for child that a parent manages state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am writing a Storybook for a child element where the parent will manage the state. For example, the `value`(string) and the `onChange`(func) are passed through props. I have both props being passed, but I'm unsure how to update the state in the storybook file.

textfield.tsx

```
import React, { FC, HTMLProps } from 'react';

type FirstNameTextFieldProps = HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>

const FirstNameTextField: FC<FirstNameTextFieldProps> = ({
    ...restOfProps
}) => (
    <input
        type="text"
        id="fname"
        name="fname"
        {...restOfProps}
    />
);

export default FirstNameTextField;
```

Storybook file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
import FirstNameTextField from './test';

export default {
    title: 'FirstNameTextField',
    component: FirstNameTextField,
    description: 'A First Name TextField.',
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => <FirstNameTextField {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
    value: 'Jason',
    onChange: () => Alert('value changed'),
};
```

My actual component is more complex, but I wanted to show the issue more easily.

Comment: Any reason to not just create a wrapper component to demo it in storybook?

Comment: @Adam If that is best practice for this type of issue, I can do it, but if there is another preferred way, I would rather do that. In your opinion, is this best practice for this issue?

Comment: Well, there's no other way to demo your components functionality, is there?

Comment: @adam, I don’t know.  This is why the question. I want to make sure Storybook doesn’t have a way to handle state.  I am creating the new storybook examples for my team, and I just want to make sure I’m doing it correctly.

Comment: Storybook has the built-in concept of [decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators). But they're more for decorating a wide variety of stories, rather than one-offs. If you can envision other components you are rendering in storybook that could make use of the context you are providing this component, use a storybook decorator. If you cannot, then just do a one-off.

Comment: @Adam I looked up decorators and I believe what you put is the correct answer. If you put this as reply I'll mark it as the answer.  thank you.